# how to open an application file(clickonce file) in xp home

Tags: file, windows-xp

The single click install applications(.application files) don't seem to be working for me on xp home.  I have just put a fresh install of xp home on my dell and I needed some additional drivers(for the nic card etc).  I downloaded the necessary drivers from dell's site using my other machine(using windows 7).  They came in a ".application" file.  I moved this application file via a flash drive to the xp machine and attempted to open it.  Windows xp told me that it did not know what program I should use to run this file.  Can someone point me in the right direction regarding this problem.  Dell didn't allow me to download an ISO instead.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

-Ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the .Net Framework 2 or above installed. ClickOnce .application files run in .Net on the client machine.

Greg